# How to realize animation of the PhysX Cloth in UE4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, physx

How to realize animation of the PhysX Cloth in UE4, like this https://youtu.be/dviWZcphcIQ?t=18s ?

Where I can find sources of the project with same animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvidia has a special clothing subcategory in physx. To use it in UE4 you have to download the APEX tool from Nvidia here: https://developer.nvidia.com/apex-clothing

You can find more information on how to import and use it in the Unreal Engine here: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Physics/Apex/index.html